# Cases environment with angle brackets

Tags: amsmath, brackets, cases

I would like to create a `cases` environment showing an angle bracket, instead of a curly one. I can't re-define the environment itself because I have to use the new environment together with the old one, that is I have to use 'curly cases' and 'angle cases' in the same document. Is there a package I could use?

Comment: What if I wanted, as well, to get 'angle brackets' departing from a single case included in a 'curly bracket'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code updates `cases` to take an optional argument. The optional argument is used as the left delimiter instead of the traditional (default) `\lbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{cases}[1][\lbrace]{%
  \def\@ldelim{#1}
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{\lbrace}{\@ldelim}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    a & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
    b & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases}[\langle]
    a & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
    b & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

It should function as expected, even if nested:

[image]

```
\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    a & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
    b & \begin{cases}[\langle]
      {} + c & \text{if $x < 7$} \\
      {} + d & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{cases}
\]
```

However, you may be better off using a regular `array`. It depends on how you nest the content.

Comment: Very nice, but unfortunately the bracket does not stretch if you set a greater line break, e.g. ``\\[3ex]``

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, what you want, you can,  with some limitations, with the `empheq` package (don't load `amsmath`: it loads `mathtools`, which loads it). The limitation is due to the `\langle` not being extensible as much as you please.  Actually, it works with two-line cases, possiblt three lines playing with the vertical spacing.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={f(x) = \empheqlangle}]{alignat*= 2}
 & \smash{x^2} + 1&\quad & \text{if }x > 0 \\
 & 1-x && \text{if }x < 0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your immediate answer; your method is ok if I want to create an independent 'angle bracket', but what if I wanted to include it as a single case of a bigger 'curly bracket'?

Comment: You might try something like `\left\langle\begin{aligned}···\end{aligned}\right.`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this other simple way by using [`scalerel` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel), to stretch the symbol `<` to desired size of a *bigdelim*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

\[
g(x) =
\stretchleftright[1000]{<}{%
\begin{aligned}\,
    ax+b, & \text{ if } x\leq 0\\
    x^2,  & \text{ if } x>0
\end{aligned}}{}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, last night I tried to stretch the left angle too, but it didn't seem to me a satisfying solution. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @fscarri No problem, I tried to propose another solution of the problem. BTW, you can also thank me with an upvote! `;-)`